# Load latex/mathematical equation in react-native-render-html

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

I am using react-native-mathjax. Still facing problems. Mathematical equation / Latex works well on the website. However, when using it react native it just displays the latex code:

`$\int_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$`

How can one load the mathematical equations in react native?

```
const mmlOptions = {
  jax: ['input/MathML'],
};

const renderers = {
  math: ({ value }) => (
    <MathJax mathJaxOptions={mmlOptions} html={value} inlineStyle={'font-size: 16px;'} />
  ),
};

//Rendering part
 <RenderHTML 
                contentWidth={width}
                source={{html: data.question.content}}
                baseStyle={{fontSize: 18}}
                tagsStyles={{sup:{color: 'red', textAlignVertical:'top'}}} 
                renderers={renderers}
 />
```